# Laravel/Cache How to set default timestamp for all keys

Tags: laravel

I'm looking for a way to set default timestamp (`$ttl`) for all cache keys so rather then this:

```php
Cache::put('key1', 'value', now()->addDay())
Cache::put('key2', 'value', now()->addDay())
.
.
.
```

I want something that check if i set something in cache configuration and the current $ttl in null ? so use my default:

```php
Cache::put('key1', 'value')
Cache::put('key2', 'value')
//default ttl is 1 day
```

I think it can be done by adding configuration to `cache.php` but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do that! However, you can build your own wrapper around it like creating a helper function.

```
// app/helpers.php

public function cache($key, $value, $minutes = 10)
{
    Cache::put($key, $value, $minutes);
}
```